# Having trouble adding a column to MySql titled after input value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hidden input within a form. When I submit the form, I want to create a new column in a table named "answers" with a title based on the value of the hidden input.

CODE FOR FORM + HIDDEN INPUT

```
<form action="frameworkplayground.php" method="POST"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="LevelColumnAdder" value="Simplifying Fractions">  
     <input type="submit" id="samplesubmitbutton" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

CODE TO TAKE THE VALUE OF THE HIDDEN INPUT (NAMED "LevelColumnAdder") ADD THE WORD "Test" TO THE VALUE & USE THIS AS THE TITLE OF A NEW COLUMN.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['LevelColumnAdder'])){
            $LevelColumnAdder=$_POST['LevelColumnAdder']; //Here, I'm trying to get the value of the input named LevelColumnAdder
            $db->query("ALTER TABLE answers ADD $LevelColumnAdder+"Test" VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");  //I know the +"Test" part is wrong but I don't know how to add "Test" to the value and use it as the new title
    }
?>
```

When this form is submitted, I ultimately want it to form a new column named "Simplifying Fractions Test" but nothing is happening.

Comment: rather unusual to alter a table structure like this. I think you need to re-access your table schema

Comment: Also no one has noticed the space in your column name so the below answers wont work .

Comment: Yes, bad in design in multiple ways.

Comment: I'm trying to learn @AbraCadaver, so if you could offer some constructive feedback, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you open a new question and give an outline of what you want to do in GENERAL, i.e. _save something that I can use to relate to some other thing later_ then you'll get some good suggestions.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I won't belabor the point but, when I've tried generic posts in the past, people get snippy for not providing specifics....can't win apparently.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @rtfm. How do I add the word "Test" to the end of the value SimplifyingFractions, though?

Answer (score 1):

You'll run into the problem of max columns very quickly.

But try `ADD COLUMN`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't quite follow though. Are you saying i should just change the line ` $db->query("ALTER TABLE answers ADD $LevelColumnAdder+"Test" VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");` to  `$db->query("ALTER TABLE answers ADD COLUMN $LevelColumnAdder+"Test" VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");` ?